# Capture stack trace from crashed mono application run as a service in Linux via mono-service

Tags: mono, mono-service

I'm running an application in Ubuntu that occasionally crashes.  I'd like to capture the stack trace when the crash occurred.  Is this possible?

I'm launching my app like this:

mono-service -m:logfile.out application.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you capturing unhandled exceptions in the application? Take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

This should allow you to at least log any unhandled exceptions so you can get a better idea what's happening.